# how to get today total data sum form mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to get today due sale. total sale row 'total' ,total paid row 'paid'.
i need get today total due.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, SUM(total) AS total, SUM(paid) AS paid FROM sma_sales WHERE DATE(`timestamp`) = CURDATE()";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo $sum = $row['total'] - $sum = $row['paid'];
    }
} else {
    echo "0.00 results";
}
```

I got result 0.00 I need view today total "due sale" amount result.
[database table screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDpDe.png)

please help.

Comment: you did not tell us what the problem is or if you have results or not and yet alone the expected result.

Comment: How can you expect us to help if you provide no real information to work with? Table structure? Sample data? Desired result?

Comment: hello friends, I add database screen shot. plz check it.

Answer (score -2):

You should do in that way making status as in your table:

```
SELECT ID FORM SMA_SALES WHERE DATA('timestap') and status == paid;
```